# How to make ripple effect without touch (dynamic) on screen in android?

Tags: android, animation, graphics, ripple

I have found ripple effect in Android but I have to touch to get effect. can anyone tell me if I want ripple effect without touch means it should effect automatically then what should I do ?

Comment: Please, share the source code so we can suggest some automatism.

Answer (score 0):

Without having seen the source my answer is very basic:
Firstly generate coordinates on screen and then just start the effect with these coordinates instead of a touch point.